# How to remove XML nodes using shell commands from xml file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to delete xml node using shell script. XML file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordType xmlns="http://soap.test.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>User_Name</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <businessProcess>Name Process</businessProcess>
    <label>Name</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Picklist1</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Test</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Picklist2</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>FirstName</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>LastName</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</RecordType>
```

As per the requirement, need to remove entire node where picklist tag is having value as `Picklist2`.  I have tried `sed` command but it is not working properly since file is having newline and spaces.

```
sed -i '' '/<picklistValues><picklist>Picklist2<\/picklist>/,/<\/picklistValues>/d' test.xml
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Use a dedicated xml tool like xmllint.

Comment: @daniu Do you have any working example

Comment: Please show the output you expect.

Comment: Your input is not well formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your input is well formed XML inside a file called test.xml containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <picklistValues>
    <picklist>Picklist1</picklist>
    <values>
      <fullName>Value1_1</fullName>
    </values>
    <values>
      <fullName>Value1_2</fullName>
    </values>
  </picklistValues>
  <picklistValues>
    <picklist>Picklist2</picklist>
    <values>
      <fullName>Value2_1</fullName>
    </values>
    <values>
      <fullName>Value2_2</fullName>
    </values>
  </picklistValues>
</root>
```

and supposing you want to remove the node corresponding to the tag `<picklistValues>` containing as child `<picklist>Picklist2</picklist>`, then you could issue:

```
xmlstarlet ed --delete '//picklistValues[picklist/text()="Picklist2"]' test.xml
```

Comment: I have corrected the format, it is same as you mentioned. but when i am trying solution in corrected xml its not working.

Comment: I have change little bit in command and now its working
`xmlstarlet ed -N N="http://soap.test.com/2006/04/metadata" --delete '//N:picklistValues[N:picklist/text()="Picklist2"]' test.xml `
Thanks @Pierre